# C# Split как правильно разделить прокси на IP и Port

Tags: c#, proxy, split

Не получается корректно разделить строку с Proxy на IP и Port.

---

Есть TextBox (tbx_Proxy), в котором построчно записаны прокси следующего вида:

```html
186.225.180.74:3128
181.143.17.37:8080
95.210.189.127:53281
139.5.71.124:23500
```

Необходимо разделить строку n на IP и Port, как это лучше сделать?

Comment: `String[] lines = TextBoxName.Text.Split(new char{'\n','\r'});` потом в цикле тоже самое с каждой строкой: `line.Split(':');`

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать класс [UriBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var ub = new UriBuilder("186.225.180.74:3128");

var host = ub.Host;
var port = ub.Port;
```

Примечание: у класса `TextBox` есть свойство [Lines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "";
        s = "186.225.180.74:3128\n";
        s += "181.143.17.37:8080\n";
        s += "95.210.189.127:53281\n";
        s += "139.5.71.124:23500";

        string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
        string[] ipPort = new string[2];
        string[,] proxy = new string[lines.Length, 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            ipPort = lines[i].Split(':');
            proxy[i, 0] = ipPort[0];
            proxy[i, 1] = ipPort[1];
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `TextBox` для перехода на новую строку использует `Environment.NewLine`, который под управлением `Windows` чаще всего равен `\r\n`, так что Ваш вариант не годится